# Send/Listen to sound in a list

Tags: buttons, ios, lists, sound

I'm presenting a list of different sounds in a list, on mobile (specifically iPhone-only)

Each cell is rectangular and has a simple one-liner label (the name of the sound), and a button on the right side of the label.

The whole cell is blank (except for the black label) and the button is a "speaker" icon.

Pressing the speaker allows  you to listen to the sound and you can see it's progress while playing.

Tapping anywhere else sends the sound. (It's sent to a user chosen in a previous screen).

This isn't the final design nor the final flow, but I thought it was a decent base for the beta. I have about 20 people testing.

I've had several feedbacks saying the sound sending/listening isn't super intuitive/user friendly/nice. No one can explain it clearly or offer a solution, but no one likes it that's for sure.

I'm really bad at this game of guessing, I'm more of a coder than an artist. 
What could make this list of sound a better experience for my users?

I was thinking that the final design for the button would help (and look more like a button), but **it doesn't make it clearer that tapping the cell will actually send the sound**. I think that is the part that my users don't like.

Here is a screenshot. Please note that I'm still only working with the bone structure, nothing is visually final, except the skeleton. (That means it can get prettier but everything should be functionally close-to-final at this stage).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative concept you could test: make it a two-step-process. Tapping on a line both plays the sound and activates the line (e.g. check mark at the left), and on the bottom you'll have a button saying "Send sound to Kyle".

In this way, you account for the fact that the user probably will send the sound that he last previewed, and the send-action is more explicit.

Comment: With that kind of concept I can even replace the speaker icon with the actual mark; i wouldn't need the speaker anymore. Or do I get it wrong?

Comment: This looks like a clean alternative, I like it

Comment: Aaah but if the sound is played every time the cell is tapped, it's gonna bve pretty annoying. So I'll mix both concepts and leave the speaker icon to play the sound, but make the cell selectable/markable for sending and add a send buton

Comment: You might be right. My idea was to facilitate discovery (similar to ring tone selection), but once you know how the sound is called you don't want it to be played over and over again. BTW you could also animate the speaker while playing the sound.

Comment: Yeah, this list is meant to be used a lot (not like ringtone discovery). And indeed, the final concepts will probably involve some animations on the cell. Right now the idea is leaning towards a "background that fills slowly as the sound file progresses".